# Difference between: VOID, PVOID, LPVOID

Tags: winapi

In the Microsoft API documentation, I have looked at the VOID, PVOID, and LPVOID data types, but I don't know the difference between them. Also, what is the meaning of LP, P, and no prefix?

I have seen this data type when using Windows API functions, but I don't know the difference between them.

Comment: Adding to the answer, PVOID/LPVOID are the same but VOID is a typedef to `void`. It's the same difference with INT and LPINT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LP` prefix is a very old leftover from the 16-bit 8086 days. At that time there were two types of pointers, near and far (AKA "long"). A near pointer (`P` prefix) had to reference something within 65536 bytes of the current segment base, while a long pointer (`LP` prefix) included a 16-bit segment base to form the 20-bit full address (the 20-bit address was calculated simply as `segment*16 + offset`).

Ever since the move to 32-bit x86 platforms, `P` and `LP` types are completely synonymous with each other (note that the 80386 actually supported a 48-bit far pointer, they simply never caught on with OS designers, they chose to use flat memory models and instead rely on the memory management unit's paging logic for access control).